# On the origin of "guten Rutsch ins neue Jahr" // Wie deutsch ist „guten Rutsch“?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, single-word-request, slang

Ich hatte nie die Bedeutung von „guten Rutsch“ verstanden. Ich habe das DWDS nachgeschlagen und das gefunden:

> Rutsch m. im Neujahrswunsch Guten Rutsch (ins Neue Jahr)! (Anfang 20. Jh.). Wohl aus jidd. rosch ‘Kopf, Erstes, Anfang’, rosch ha schono ‘Neujahr’

Das wird auch irgendwie durch das Wiktionary [bestätigt](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/guten_Rutsch_ins_neue_Jahr):

> Verbreitet ist die Ansicht, dass die Formel „guter Rutsch“ nicht auf das deutsche Substantiv Rutsch (von rutschen) zurückgeht. Sie ist eine Verballhornung des hebräisch/jiddischen Rosch ha-Schana → WP (auch Rosch ha-Schanah, in aschkenasischer Aussprache Rausch ha-Schono oder Roisch ha-Schono oder volkstümlich auf Jiddisch auch Roscheschune genannt; hebräisch רֹאשׁ הַשָּׁנָה‎ (CHA: rōʾš ha-šānāh)  „Haupt des Jahres“, „Anfang des Jahres“). „Rosch ha-Schana“ ist der hebräische Name für den Neujahrstag.

Wenn ich richtig verstehe, ist *Rutsch* eine Eindeutschung des hebräischen Ausdrucks für „Anfang des Jahres“. (So wird das Ganze „guten Rutsch ins neue Jahr“ irgendwie eine zweisprachige Wiederholung. Aber zurück zum Thema.)

**Frage:**

Kürzlich empfing ich aber einen Brief mit folgendem Inhalt:

> und hoffe, dass (…) du gut ins neue Jahr gerutscht bist!

Das verstehe ich aber wie das Perfekt von *rutschen* in der Bedeutung von *gleiten*. Ich mag diesen Satz aber.

- ist es grammatisch richtig (und optimal), so *Rutsch* zu benutzen, selbst wenn dessen Ursprung keine verbale Form ist?

Comment: Das `guter Rutsch` jiddischen Ursprungs ist, war mir nicht bewusst (mal wieder was gelernt. Ich ging bisher davon aus, es hat was mit der kalten Jahreszeit und dem Wunsch nicht auszurutschen zu tun hat). Ich nehme an, so geht es den meisten Deutschsprachigen. Da `rutschen` auch ein deutsches Wort ist, wird es auch als solches verwendet. D.h. die Verwendung ist - wie in der Frage geschrieben - wirklich eine verbale.

Comment: Was heißt schon richtig? Der Ursprung ist den Leuten nicht mehr bewusst, Rutsch wird als Bild für den Übergang verstanden.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laut [Sendung mit der Maus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2i7UKqATIz4) ist Rutsch ein altes Wort für Reise und man wünscht sich eine gute Reise ins nächste Jahr. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guten_Rutsch) sieht das ähnlich und erwähnt als Alternative auch die Erklärung mit dem Jiddischen die knut geschrieben hat. Wenn Du rutschen als Wort für reisen ansiehst, ist "gut gerutscht" = "gut gereist" natürlich richtig; zumindest im übertragenen Sinne.

Answer (score 2):

Ja, der Ursprung ist den meisten Deutschen wohl nicht bekannt und es ist daher definitiv weit verbreitet, das Verb "rutschen" zu verwenden.

> Rutsch gut rein!
>
> Ich hoffe, du bist gut reingerutscht.

Comment: Ist das, also, nur typisch deutsch und hört man das nicht in Österreich und/oder der Schweiz?

Comment: Schön, dann auch so Sprüche wie "Guten Rutsch, aber rutscht nicht zu weit!"

Comment: @c.p. Wird bei uns in der Schweiz genauso verwendet, natürlich mit Mundart-Aussprache, aber sonst ganz genauso.

Comment: Ebenso für Österreich.