# Translation of "wish you all the best"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

> I wish you **all the best** for the upcoming year.

Would it be idiomatic to say the following?

> Ich wünsche dir all das Beste für das kommende Jahr.

A close and natural translation would be

> Ich wünsche dir alles Gute für das kommende Jahr.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Robert pointed out, *"All das Beste"* or *"Alles Beste"* is too uncommon to use it.

A much more frequently encountered way of putting this would be:

> Ich wünsche Dir für das kommende/neue Jahr **nur** das Beste!

It doesn't mean *all the best* but rather *only the best*. It's however used a lot.

Check [this out](http://www.nug.rwth-aachen.de/index.php?main_action=detail&main_id=109&) for a usage example. It's from a university website.

Answer (score 10):

"All das Beste" oder "alles Beste" ist eine wörtliche Übersetzung, die in Deutschland unüblich ist. Man wünschte generell "alles Gute" (zum Geburtstag, zum neuen Jahr) oder zum Jahreswechsel einen "guten Rutsch".

Siehe auch [On the origin of "guten Rutsch ins neue Jahr" // Wie deutsch ist „guten Rutsch“?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9476/on-the-origin-of-guten-rutsch-ins-neue-jahr-wie-deutsch-ist-guten-rutsch)

Answer (score 3):

I would say:

Ich wünsche dir das Beste für das kommende Jahr.

Answer (score 3):

> Ich wünsche Dir alles erdenklich Gute für das kommende Jahr!