# Übersetzung von "wish you the best of luck"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

> I wish you the best of luck for your upcoming exam.

Wie übersetzt man das ins Deutsche? Man kann

> Ich wünsche dir viel Glück für deine kommende Prüfung.

sagen, was die gleiche Bedeutung hat, aber ein bisschen anders ausgedrückt ist. Gibt es eine nähere Phrase, wie die Folgende?

> Ich wünsche dir das  beste Glück ...

(Bemerkung: Verwandt, aber nicht dieselbe [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18503/translation-of-wish-you-all-the-best).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wie wäre es mit Folgendem:

> Ich wünsche dir alles erdenklich Gute für die anstehende Prüfung!